# iOS Swift 3 tableview custom cell error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to add a custom cell to tableview in Swift3 but getting a strange error. Here is the screenshot of error.

[image]

Comment: post actual code, not screenshots of code.

Comment: @luk2302 In this case, just actual code wouldn't have been very helpful in determining the problem.

Comment: @CaseyWagner: a screenshot additionally is fine if it helps, but we want the line of code as text here, for the benefit of screen readers and search engines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `indexPath` in place of `IndexPath` like this:

```
let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

Also, make sure that `CustomCell` is subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Thanks, Working now

Answer (score 2):

Replace the placeholder `IndexPath` with lowercase `indexPath`

Placeholders – with a light blue background – are tokens which indicate the expected types of the parameters.

But you got more serious issues than that error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CustomCell` class does not inherit from `UITableViewCell`. Change it to:

```
class CustomCell:UITableViewCell {
    // your custom cell implementation
}
```